# when my fragment is clicked list view in that get dubbles

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, fragment, tabbar, listview-adapter

i am using fragment with swipeable tab bar, in which one of the fragment i am adding on edit text through which i am searching the listview items .
i am adding listview items through srting array in the string resources.
the problem starts when i swipe fragments and come to the fragment in which i have used listview or tabbed the tab bar the items in the listview automatically produce new copy of the previous items i.e the items get doubble or tripple or as number of times when ever my fragment is created as i added the listview oncreatview in the fragment.

code of fragment in which i am adding listview

```
public class HingDict extends Fragment {

ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;
    Resources res;
    ArrayList<Dictionary> arraylist = new ArrayList<Dictionary>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.hingdict,container,false);


        res=getResources();
        String hinglish[]=res.getStringArray(R.array.hinglish);
        String english[]=res.getStringArray(R.array.english);


        list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for (int i = 0; i < hinglish.length; i++) 
        {
            Dictionary dc = new Dictionary(hinglish[i],
                    english[i]);
             arraylist.add(dc); 

        }

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        editsearch = (EditText)view. findViewById(R.id.search);


        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

code of listview adapter class

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Dictionary> dictionarylist = null;
    private ArrayList<Dictionary> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Dictionary> dictionarylist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.dictionarylist = dictionarylist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Dictionary>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(dictionarylist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView hinglish;
        TextView english;
        //TextView impression;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dictionarylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Dictionary getItem(int position) {
        return dictionarylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);


            holder.hinglish = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hinglish);
            holder.english = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.english);
        //  holder.impression=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.impression);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        holder.hinglish.setText(dictionarylist.get(position).getHinglish());
        holder.english.setText(dictionarylist.get(position).getEnglish());
        //holder.impression.setText(dictionarylist.get(position).getImpression());


        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);



                intent.putExtra("hinglish",(dictionarylist.get(position).getHinglish()));

                intent.putExtra("english",(dictionarylist.get(position).getEnglish()));
                //intent.putExtra("impression",(dictionarylist.get(position).getImpression()));

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        dictionarylist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            dictionarylist.addAll(arraylist);
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (Dictionary dc : arraylist) 

                if (dc.getHinglish().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                {
                    dictionarylist.add(dc);
                }
            }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call  `arraylist.clear();` before adding in for loop as :

```
arraylist.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < hinglish.length; i++) 
        {
            Dictionary dc = new Dictionary(hinglish[i],
                    english[i]);
             arraylist.add(dc); 

        }
```